# Multi-merge algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, generics

As you know there is an algorithm in C++ standard library called `std::merge`, that merges two sorted ranges into another range. I try to write another merge (called `multi_merge`) that gets multiple sorted ranges (one or more), and merged them in one.
The code is as follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<typename I>
using range = std::pair<I, I>;

template<typename I>
struct is_empty_range {
    bool operator()(const range<I>& x) const {
        return x.first == x.second;
    }
};

template<typename I, typename Compare>
struct range_compare {
    range_compare(Compare comp) : comp_{ comp } {}
    bool operator()(const range<I>& x, const range<I>& y) const {
        return comp_(*x.first, *y.first);
    }

    Compare comp_;
};

template<typename I, typename O, typename Compare>
O multi_merge(std::vector<range<I>> inputs, O output, Compare comp) {
    inputs.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(inputs), std::end(inputs), is_empty_range<I>{}),
        std::end(inputs));

    if (inputs.empty())
        return output;

    while (inputs.size() != 1) {
        auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(inputs), std::end(inputs), range_compare<I, Compare>{comp});
        if (min->first != min->second) {
            *output = *min->first;
            ++min->first;
            ++output;
        }
        else {
            inputs.erase(min);
        }
    }

    return std::copy(inputs[0].first, inputs[0].second, output);
}

template<typename I, typename O>
O multi_merge(std::vector<range<I>> inputs, O output) {
    return multi_merge(inputs, output, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type>{});
}
```

I want to know your opinions about this code, especially the way I'm passing list of ranges (a `vector` of `pair`s of iterators) to the algorithm. Do you recommend a more general way?

Here is a simple piece of code to test the algorithm:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr size_t count = 10000;
    std::vector<int> v(count);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

    using it_t = std::vector<int>::iterator;
    std::vector<range<it_t>> inputs;
    for (auto part = 0u; part <= count - 1000; part += 1000)
        inputs.emplace_back(v.begin() + part, v.begin() + part + 1000);

    for (auto r : inputs)
        std::sort(r.first, r.second);

    std::vector<int> output;
    output.reserve(count);

    multi_merge(inputs, std::back_inserter(output));

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "output size is correct: "
        << (output.size() == count) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "output is sorted: "
        << std::is_sorted(output.begin(), output.end()) << '\n';
}
```

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/o3d2zw)

Comment: It might be helpful if you copied the test from the link to here. You leave the link, but links may break.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Added!

Comment: Can't you just iterate `std::merge` on the ranges? Just pick an optimal order so at each iteration you merge two similarly sized ranges. I think it will be faster.

Comment: @ALX23z It depends. Suppose that you are merging several streams (files, ...).

Comment: @E.Vakili with slow streams (like network) of unclear size you'd better make a multi threaded version that performs pair merging. But it requires synchronization procedures as well as "try_read" instructions - so current interface doesn't fit.

Comment: @ALX23z Parallelizing such algorithms is another topic that is also true about `std::merge`. But what about file merging? Although for normal ranges, using `std::merge` requires more memory as temp storage for intermediate merges, and more time because of iterating over each element times and times again. In the above algorithm each element in each range only visited once.

Comment: @E.Vakili no in the above algo you visit each element multiple times - too many times if there are many ranges - which is why it is inefficient for sorting multiple vectors. If you sort file streams bigger bottleneck is reading the files - and if you read multiple files they might slow each other. So I advise more thought into such matters.

Comment: @ALX23z Thanks. I think I missed the point and should do some measurements. I find your notes are at least as better as other answers below.

Answer (score 4):

- **Efficiency**

  The algorithm is suboptimal. Selecting a `min` is linear in the number of ranges. Arranging them in a priority queue would make it logarithmic.
- **Correctness**

  Testing for `(min->first != min->second)` is done too late. `min->first == min->second` means that the empty range participated in the comparison. Which in turn means that the end of that range was dereferenced. UB is imminent.

  Since

  ```
  inputs.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(inputs), std::end(inputs), is_empty_range<I>{}),
  std::end(inputs));
  ```

  guarantees that there are no empty ranges at the beginning, I recommend to rewrite the loop as

  ```
  while (inputs.size() != 1) {
      auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(inputs), std::end(inputs), range_compare<I, Compare>{comp});
      *output = *min->first;
      ++min->first;
      ++output;

      if (min->first != min->second) {
          inputs.erase(min);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain more about usage of priority queues?

Answer (score 1):

It could be my very old eyes, but it seems like this is just a copy rather than a merge, or at least the test is, I don't see where `output` is being filled with any content prior to the merge.

### Obsolete C++

In the `main()` function the code is using `std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());`, this was [depreciated in C++14 and removed from C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

### Good Habit in C++ and C

Mostly for code maintenance reasons, but also for readability, it is a good habit to wrap the code in if statement or loops in braces (`{}`) even if the code is only a single statement. This makes it easier to modify the code in the future, and prevents the insertion of bugs in the future when the maintainer is in a rush. Lots of bugs have been caused have been caused by coders adding a single line of code in an if statement or loop.

```
    if (inputs.empty())
        return output;
```

is not as maintainable as:

```
    if (inputs.empty())
    {
        return output;
    }
```

*Note `multi_merge(std::vector<range<I>> inputs, O output, Compare comp)` is inconsistent in the use of braces.*

### Avoid Magic Numbers

In `main()` a symbolic constant is created for `count`, which is 10000, but no symbolic constant is defined for 1000. It would make the code easier to read if it was consistent and there was a symbolic constant for 1000 as well

Comment: Thanks, but the test code is only here as a sample for usage of `multi_merge`. I want your thoughts on the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the algorithm is a bit inefficient (especially when you get a large number of input ranges). Each time around the while loop you are finding the min value you are checking all the ranges.

Rather than doing this I would build a heap. Then extract the top value from the heap each iteration. The value that was extracted (should be value and original range) you can then pull the next value from the original range and add it to the heap. Rince and repeat.

This converts your `O(n.m)` to `O(n.log(m))` (n assume each sorted list has n elements and there are m lists).

```
std::vector<Range<I>>   topOfEachHeap;
for(auto r: input) {
    topOfEachHeap.emplace_back(r);
    std::push_heap(std::begin(topOfEachHeap), std::end(topOfEachHeap), comp);
}

while (!topOfEachHeap.empty()) {
    std::pop_heap(std::begin(topOfEachHeap), std::end(topOfEachHeap), comp);
    *output = *(topOfEachHeap.back().first);

    ++topOfEachHeap.back().first;
    ++output;

    if (topOfEachHeap.back().empty()) {
       topOfEachHeap.pop_back();
    }
    else {
       std::push_heap(std::begin(topOfEachHeap), std::end(topOfEachHeap), comp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard library algorithms use, by default, the `<` operator to compare values, instead of `std::less<T>`, which can be specialized for different types with different meanings, with pointers being a case in point. Interestingly, `std::less<>` (which is equivalent to `std::less<void>`) is specially defined to provide transparent comparison semantics with the `<` operator. Therefore, this:

```
template<typename I, typename O>
O multi_merge(std::vector<range<I>> inputs, O output) {
    return multi_merge(inputs, output, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type>{});
}
```

Should be changed to

```
template<typename I, typename O>
O multi_merge(std::vector<range<I>> inputs, O output) {
    return multi_merge(inputs, output, std::less<>{});
}
```

To keep consistent with the standard library conventions.

Comment: You are true but then it can be used with C++14 and above. The original code is tested against C++11.

Comment: @E.Vakili Roll our your own then. It’s no longer than 5 lines.